# Как писать Property на Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios7

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) LGFilterView  *filterView1;
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_filterView1 initWithTitles:<#(NSArray *)#>];}
```

Так я сделал на Obj-C необходим метод initWithTitles из LGFilterView

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {    
var filterView1:LGFilterView!
```

Так я сделал на Swift, но он вообще не видит методы при вызове

Вот сама библиотека:
https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGFilterView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы в своем проекте создаете первый swift класс, xcode вас спросит, хотите ли вы создать bridging header. жмите 'да' и в созданном хедере импортируйте свой LGFilterView

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "LGFilterView.h"
```

Comment: без изменений, также не видит методы

Comment: исправил ответ.

Comment: Да, она подключена через бридж хедер, также через Carthage создавал .framework и подключал, результат был тот же

Comment: у меня ваш пример, после подключения header работает отлично

Comment: Если у вас из методов получается вызвать initWithTitles, то скиньте как вы вызываете. У меня только .init(titles: ...) и другие c init выходят

Comment: initWithTitles и init(titles) это один и тот же метод просто у objC и  свифта разные нотации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все свелось к моему незнанию как использовать эту библиотеку.